# Why does this program to read a file cause an endless loop?

Tags: perl

I wanted to find a program to read and write a file line by line.

Googling I found [***How to Read and Write Files in Perl***](https://www.thoughtco.com/read-and-write-files-in-perl-2641155)
on the first page of results.
It includes the following code to read a file and write every line to stdout:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

open(MYFILE, 'data.txt');

while ( ) {
    chomp;
    print "$_\n";
}

close(MYFILE);
```

When I run this program (using Perl 5.18.2 on Ubuntu) it endlessly prints newlines until I stop it. What's the problem?

Comment: What a uniquely awful site. The `<MYFILE>` doesn't even show up when you view source, which means they copy-pasted it from another site that already wasn't rendering the HTML correctly.

Comment: Why `chomp` just to add `\n` on the next line? Also, lexical filehandles. Also, 3-argument `open`. Also, check system calls for failure.

Comment: There is a very good list of resources on the Stack Overflow [Perl tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/info). Any one of them would be a better choice than the site you have happened upon.

Answer (score 2):

The while statement above is incorrect: "while ()" is the same as "while (1)" and causes an endless loop.

Change the line as follows, and the code works:

```
while (<MYFILE>) {
```